# JGraph disable handles/connections on Vertexes

Tags: java, jgraph

Im am trying to disable connections on all my (sub) vertexes that i use for showing cell icons/labels.
When i do run the following code the inserted vertex is still somehow connectable.

```
    labelCellObject = (mxCell)getGraph().insertVertex(this, "labelCell", "", 0, 0, 10, 8, "");
    labelCell.setVertex(true);
    labelCell.setConnectable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The names of the objects are different. If you change, in the first line, from `labelCellObject` to `labelCell` like in the following lines, I guess it should work.